# Search - Appscript - targetRange column start is not at the column I ask for

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am still learning a lot about Apps Script and needed to make a sheet for my work.
At the moment I am busy on a Search function.
The only problem is that the results that I want to get, do not go to that column.
Only to a column way further.

```
function Search() {
  var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source");
  //USER INPUT
  sourceRowStart = 2; //Row to start getting formulas from
  sourceColumnStart = 13; //Column to start getting formulas from
  numberOfSourceColumnsToGet = 9; //Number of columns to get formulas from    
  targetRowStart = 4; //Row to start copying formulas to
  targetRange = 1; //Column to start copying formulas to
  //END OF USER INPUT
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sourceRange = activeSheet.getRange(sourceRowStart, sourceColumnStart, activeSheet.getLastRow(), numberOfSourceColumnsToGet);
  sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();//Get only formulas from the source rang
  targetRange = activeSheet.getRange(targetRowStart, targetRange, sourceFormulas.length, sourceFormulas[0].length);
  targetRange.setFormulas(sourceFormulas);//Copy the formulas to the target range
}
```

**Following is the link of a test-sheet for this question:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b5Xa1z6xdeqyFbAVtxwc-U76iDteC1Sn46Ll_v9WGPU/edit#gid=713972882

**Thankyou in advance to whoever could help me out!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Search() {
  const ssr = 2; 
  const ssc = 13; 
  const sncols = 9;  
  const tsr = 4; 
  const tsc = 1;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  const sfA = sh.getRange(ssr, ssc, sh.getLastRow() - ssr + 1, sncols).getFormulas();
  sh.getRange(tsr, tsc, sfA.length, sfA[0].length).setFormulas(sfA);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer! It is still giving it in the wrong column.
It gives the results starting in column 6.

Comment: It gets datta from the source  starting column 13 and it get 9 columns and it puts them in  to row 4 column 1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it causes the error in this case, but anyway. You have the line:

```
targetRange = 1; //Column to start copying formulas to
```

And then:

```
targetRange = activeSheet.getRange(targetRowStart, targetRange, sourceFormulas.length, sourceFormulas[0].length);
```

You're using the same variable `targetRange` for different purposes. It's not a good practice. It can get you glitches sometimes.

And to be honest, from yours spreadsheet and the code I failed to understand how the desired result should look like. Is the `activeSheet` supposed to be 'Database' sheet or 'Source' sheet, or something else? Etc.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer!
The 'Source' is where I want the information to go to and the 'Database' is where I want to pull the data from.
Which variables can I use best?
I am still new and learning about this.
Thankyou so much already for your tips!

Comment: You can use about any names for variables. But it's better if they have different names. For example, in this case the variables could be `targetColStart` and `targetRange`. As for the question, could you just fill the sheet manually? To show how it should looks like after the script.